# Why Invalid location of text in tag form? even if I remove the tag form

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

Why am I getting a warning: Invalid location of text (<%= table %>) in tag ()?

By removing the line:  `<form name= index action=update method=get ></form>` , the warning remains.

When running just this file on server I get null instead of a table.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>


<%
    String table=(String) request.getAttribute("table");

%>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>content</title>

</head>
<form name= index action=update method=get ></form>
<body>

<h1>content</h1>

<p>
<a href="read">data</a>
</p>

<%= table %> --------------Invalid location of text (<%= table %>) in tag (<form>).
<br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML itself appears to have problems.  Why do you have a `<form>` tag completely outside the `<body>` of the page?  You should fix this first, then see if the JSP error persists (I see nothing wrong with your JSP code, by the way).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen should the whole form tag  be inside the body? <form name= index action=update method=get ></form>

Comment: Yes, it should.  Maybe it would work as you have it, but it's not correct HTML.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the warning remains

Comment: looks like reopening the project fixes the issue.

Comment: No, my guess is that your browser had an old version cached.  Put back the code as in your question, clear the cache, and reload, and I'll bet it will still fail.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the table still doesn't appear, but the warning disapears

Comment: Is the 'table' attribute being set before directing to this jsp? The null is the printing of a null table or others?